# ionic deploy alternatives?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

What alternatives do they exist with the same functionality as the ionic deploy service?
Is there any other Cordova plugin that provides the ability to make a live update, without resubmitting to the app store or the play store?

Answer (score 2):

One alternative that I have found is called Code Push
http://microsoft.github.io/code-push/
but the problem is that some have reported being rejected from Apple during the review process of their app.

---

Another alternative that I have found is https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push-cli but I am not sure how robust this solution is comparing it to the real ionic deploy service.